# onChange firing when picker value not selected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a login form with conditional statements to display option lists, when a user selects a value from the first picker (Year), the picker below is displayed (Group), when a group is selected the third picker is displayed.

I have set functions to each pickers `onChange`.

This works fine until I start changing selected values. If I reselect a Year value from the first picker, `this.onGroupChange` is invoked on the second picker (Group).

Why is this invoked when that picker's value hasn't changed? How can I prevent firing when a previous value is changed?

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: ""
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onStudentChange = this.onStudentChange.bind(this);
    this.onGroupChange = this.onGroupChange.bind(this);
    this.onParentChange = this.onParentChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {}

onParentChange(e) {
    const { setYear: year } = this.props.credentials;

    this.props.dispatch(setYear(e));
}

onGroupChange(e) {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { setYear } = this.props.credentials;

    const { categories } = this.props.categories;
    if (e !== null) {
         this.props.dispatch(setGroup(e, categories, setYear));
    }
}

onStudentChange(e) {
    if (e !== "") {
        this.props.dispatch(setStudent(e));
    }
}

onSubmit(e) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Month");
}

render() {
    const {
        setYear,
        setGroup,
        setStudent,
        showStudent
    } = this.props.credentials;
    const categories = this.props.categories;
    const isLoading = this.props.isLoading;

    if (isLoading || !categories) {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" />
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                source={require("../img/logoGreen.png")}
                style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }}
            />

            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={setYear}
                    label="Year"
                    onChange={this.onParentChange}
                    options={categories}
                />
                {setYear ? (
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={setGroup}
                        label="Group"

                        // invoked when picker above is changed.

                        onChange={this.onGroupChange}
                        options={
                            categories.find(category => {
                                return category.id == setYear;
                            }).options
                        }
                    />
                ) : null}
                {setGroup && showStudent ? (
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={setStudent}
                        label="Student"
                        onChange={this.onStudentChange}
                        options={
                            categories
                                .find(category => {
                                    return category.id == setYear;
                                })
                                .options.find(category => {
                                    return category.id == setGroup;
                                }).options
                        }
                    />
                ) : null}
                {(setYear && setGroup && !showStudent) || setStudent ? (
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={this.onSubmit}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Submit</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                ) : null}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: I guess change is a change;) but you could check in handler that value is the same and not progress with it?

Comment: in onParentChange, you rename setYear to year, but call setYear inside dispatch. I don't know how this is even working.

In onGroupChange, you dispatch setGroup but don't destructure the setGroup from this.props.credentials. Again, no idea how it's working? Are these redux actions you are importing from some other file?